# Как получить размер файла в 7-zip архиве?

Tags: c#, 7z

Использую `SevenZipSharp`.

`SevenZipExtractor` имеет свойство `ArchiveFileData`, через которое можно получить данные о файлах в архиве. В этих данных содержится свойство `Size`, получающее размер *распакованного* файла.

```
SevenZipExtractor sze = new SevenZipExtractor("test.7z", "123");
foreach (var f in sze.ArchiveFileData)
{
    MessageBox.Show(f.Size.ToString());
}
```

Как получить размер *сжатого* файла?

Comment: А почему бы не посмотреть размер архива?

Comment: @Алексей Саровский в архиве же не один файл

Comment: Ага... Я думаю, что никак. Как происходит сжатие? скорее всего по словарю. То есть если вы сжимаете несколько файлов, то на сжатие данного влияют все остальные.

Comment: Серии выбираются из всех участвующих в сжатии файлов. Поэтому сжать один файл или несколько - вещи разные абсолютно.

Answer (score 3):

Ответил вам на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34403375/1985167), приведу тут перевод своего ответа.

---

По всей видимости SevenZipSharp не заполняет эту информацию. Вот например как заполняется размер в распакованном виде для `ArchiveFileInfo`:

```
var fileInfo = new ArchiveFileInfo { Index = (int)i };
...
_archive.GetProperty(i, ItemPropId.Size, ref data);
fileInfo.Size = NativeMethods.SafeCast<ulong>(data, 0);
```

В перечислении `ItemPropId` есть свойство `PackedSize`, однако оно не используется, видимо потому что может отсутствовать (если верить комментарию):

```
/// <summary>
/// Item packed sise; usually absent
/// </summary>
PackedSize,
```

Так что видимо единственный способ получить это значение, это форкнуть SevenZipSharp и попытаться пофиксить самому (или поискать среди существующих форков). Если это в принципе возможно.

Comment: А как все-таки, если много файлов. пакуются же все сразу. И в архиве из n файлов "доля" файла не равна размеру, если этот файл отдельно сжать. Мне кажется, что не все так просто.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский видимо потому и не заполняется эта информация, что не все так просто :). Я лишь ответил, что размер файла не получить, но раз проект опенсорсный, то можно попробовать это сделать самому. *"Если это в принципе возможно."*

Comment: @andreycha,  COM-интерфейс 7zip при отсутствующих свойствах во всех хендлерах вполне корректно возвращает `S_FALSE`, а SevenZipSharp в этом случае просто не заполняет соответствующее свойство. Какую-то потенциальную ошибку, за которую будет ответственен именно SevenZipSharp, тут придумать довольно сложно. Скорей всё же просто "не хватило времени" - в самом начале развития проекта на автора свалились долгожданные жена и ребенок, и работа над проектом была скоропостижно заброшена. После него никто разбирать и сопровождать ту "кашу" так и не решился.